# Create base classes with base class lists

Tags: c#

I have `Bill`s and `Receipt`s. Both types have a property called `Lines`, but `Receipt.Lines` is full of `ReceiptLine`s and `Bill.Lines` is full of `BillLine`s. I'd like them to both inherit from a class called `Document` with a property `Lines` that's full of `DocumentLine`s so that I can occasionally pass them to functions that operate on `Document`s, but I don't want to have to `myReceipt.Lines.Select(line => (ReceiptLine)line)` each time I am specifically using a `Bill` or `Receipt`. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Note that the following attempt results in `CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Receipt' to 'Document<DocumentLine>'`

```cs
void Main()
{
    var something = new Receipt();
    DoStuff(something);
}
public void DoStuff(Document<DocumentLine> document) { }

public abstract class DocumentLine { }
public class BillLine : DocumentLine { }
public class ReceiptLine : DocumentLine { }
public abstract class Document<TDocLine> where TDocLine : DocumentLine
{
    public List<TDocLine> Lines { get; set; }
}
public class Bill : Document<BillLine> { }
public class Receipt : Document<ReceiptLine> { }
```

Comment: Override the `Lines` property on `Bill` and `Receipt`?

Comment: Make `ReceiptLine` and `BillLine` and `DocumentLine` implent an interface like `IDocumentLine`

Comment: You can accomplish this with inheritance, but it can create some regrettable coupling between two classes that inherit from the same base class. An interface is an ideal choice. Mapping both types to a third type is an option. If these two types don't already inherit from a base class for natural reasons that already existed, I wouldn't add inheritance to cause them both to have something in common.

Comment: My apologies, I just realized you added an additional question. I have adjusted my answer to reflect the new issue.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a generic type to define the List item type, like so:

```
interface DocumentLine { }
class BillLine : DocumentLine { }
class ReceiptLine : DocumentLine { }

class Document<T> where T : DocumentLine
{
    public List<T> Lines { get; set; }
}

class Bill : Document<BillLine> { }

class Receipt : Document<ReceiptLine>   { }
```

**Edit:** What the new implied question is referring to is called '[Generic Covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)'. In C# generic covariance is limited to interface and delegate types [see [out keyword (generic modifier)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier)].

Instead, to get the behavior you want, you'll have to carry the generic variable as generic with conditions, rather than a fixed covariant type.

```
public void DoStuff<T>(Document<T> document) where T : DocumentLine { }
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that you cannot change a type when overriding, but you can make the line type a generic parameter.

```
public abstract class DocumentLine { ... }
public class BillLine : DocumentLine { ... }
public class ReceiptLine : DocumentLine { ... }

public abstract class Document<TDocLine> where TDocLine : DocumentLine
{
    public List<TDocLine> Lines { get; set; }
}

public class Bill : Document<BillLine> { ... }
public class Receipt : Document<ReceiptLine> { ... }
```

Deriving the line types from a common base has advantages. 1) you can reuse stuff common to both line types. 2) You can limit the actual types of `TDocLine`. This safer as it disallows you to specify an inappropriate type and it allows you to access the common members declared in `DocumentLine` from other methods in the `Document<TDocLine>` class.